# Writing interceptors for parameter annotations using Guice

Tags: java, annotations, aop, guice, interceptor

#### Main References for My Question:

- Writing Method Interceptors for Google Guice: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP
- The JavaDoc for the MethodInterceptor interface: http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/doc/org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor.html
- General references about Java annotations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

---

#### Now My Question:

I am writing a Java application that heavily relies on Google Guice for creating objects and handling dependency injection. I am trying to use interceptors to run pre-processing code before certain annotated methods are executed. So far, I have successfully been able to execute interceptors (using the `MethodInterceptor` interface) on methods that have been annotated, using Guice's instructions. However, I want to now write interceptors that will execure on *Parameter Annotations*.

Here is an example scenario. First, I create my own annotation. For example::

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface MyParameterAnnotation {
}
```

Next, I write my own interceptor for this annotation:

```
public class MyParameterAnnotationInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
       // Do some stuff
       return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how I intend on using `@MyParameterAnnotation`:

```
public class ExampleObject {
    public String foo(@MyParameterAnnotation String param) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, I need to create a Guice Injector and use it to create an instalce of `ExampleObject`, or else I cannot use a method interceptor in this project. I configure the Injector so that the `MyParameterAnnotationInterceptor` is bound to `@MyParameterAnnotation`, like so:

```
final MethodInterceptor interceptor = new MyParameterAnnotationInterceptor();
requestStaticInjection(MyParameterAnnotationInterceptor.class);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MyParameterAnnotation.class), interceptor);
```

When I follow the above steps and execute a call to `ExampleObject.foo()`, unfortunately the interceptor is not executed despite the parameter being marked by `@MyParameterAnnotation`. Note that these similar steps will work if the annotation was placed at the *method level* instead.

This leads me to come up with two possible conclusions: either Guice cannot support binding an interceptor to a parameter annotation, or I am doing something completely incorrect (perhaps I should use another AOP Alliance interface for the interceptor, like [FieldInterceptor](http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/doc/org/aopalliance/intercept/FieldInterceptor.html), but I highly doubt it because the [JavaDoc for Guice's AbstractModule](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#bindInterceptor%28com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%3E,%20com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher%3C?%20super%20java.lang.reflect.Method%3E,%20org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor...%29) suggests that the `bindInterceptor()` method can only use a `MethodInterceptor` parameter).

Nonetheless, all help us much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matcher is for method annotations not method parameter annotations.

There is no matcher provided by Guice for method parameter annotations--you either have to write one yourself or use some other scheme. Note that this is a bit of an odd use case--Generally you can get away with

```
public class ExampleObject {
    @MyAnnotation
    public String foo(String param) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You have the right Guice interceptor config for the above example.